# AngularJS $http.interceptors.push Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set access-token to the header after a login is successful. I'm trying to achieve it by using interceptors but getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- TokenInterceptor <- $http <- $compile
```

**JS**

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider',function ($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
}]);

myApp.factory('TokenInterceptor', function ($q, $window, $location, AuthenticationService) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },

        requestError: function(rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },

        response: function (response) {
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },

        //Revoke client authentication if 401 is received

        responseError: function(rejection) {
            console.log("Rejecton !");
            console.log(rejection);

            if (rejection != null && rejection.status === 401 && ($window.sessionStorage.token || AuthenticationService.isLogged)) {
                console.log("Revoked !");
                delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
                AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
                $location.path("/admin/login");
            }

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: looks like the problem is caused by minified version, are your using `ng-annotate` to process your source before uglifying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
yApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    var interceptor = ['$q', '$window', '$location', '$injector', function($q, $window, $location, $injector) {

        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },

            requestError: function(rejection) {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            response: function (response) {
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            // Revoke client authentication if 401 is received

            responseError: function(rejection) {
                console.log(rejection);
                // Dynamically get the service since they can't be injected into config
                var AuthenticationService = $injector.get('AuthenticationService');

                if (rejection != null && rejection.status === 401 && ($window.sessionStorage.token || AuthenticationService.isLogged)) {
                    delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
                    AuthenticationService.isLogged = false;
                    $location.path("/login");
                }

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }];

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you uglify the source , `TokenInterceptor` is resolved to `a` which can't be found in angular context.

you can use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to pre-process your source before uglify, it will auto convert your srouce code to use explicit annotations (array) style `myApp.factory('TokenInterceptor', ['$q', '$window', '$location', 'AuthenticationService', function ($q, $window, $location, AuthenticationService){...}])`to be minified-safe

`ng-annotate` has `grunt` and `gulp` plugins as well